# Merging two Laravel queries with union - pagination not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got two large queries (they come from two SQL Server views) that I need to merge to display in a table and have the ability to sort and search. There are a few million rows so pagination is a must. The two queries contain different data but are formatted to fit within the same table and the rows are interspersed with each other depending on the sort.

```
// Trivial example for demonstration
$queryA = ModelA::select("A, B, C");
$queryB = ModelB::select("A, D as B, C");

$queryA->union($queryB);

$queryA->where("A", "=", "search");

return $queryA->paginate(5);
```

The pagination doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting all of the results from both queries. Is it possible to paginate these results using Eloquent without having to `->get()` the entire result set?

Comment: you mean you can get the data but you want it to get it by some size or the union is not working

Comment: @Basharmal sorry I've updated the question...my problem was having an error in my select statement causing the union to fail. I'm now trying to get pagination working but it looks like that may not be simple.

Answer (score 0):

try use this code

```
$queryA = ModelA::select("A, B, C");
$queryB = ModelB::select("A, D as B, C");

$queryA->where("A", "=", "search");

$query = $queryA->unionAll($queryB);

return $query->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both select statements are wrong.

Try this

```
$queryB = ModelB::select('A as B', 'D as C');
    $queryA = ModelA::select('A', 'B', 'C')
    ->where("A", "=", "search")
    ->union($queryB)
    ->paginate(15);
    
    
    return $queryA;
```